# How to retrieve the complete process name with "tasklist" cmd?

Tags: windows, cmd

The process name returned by "tasklist" command is limited to 25 characters, so the question is: how to get the complete process name?

Comment: `tasklist /fo csv` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options.  You ask about the full name, so you can use

```
tasklist /fo list | find "Image Name"
```

That does include the words "Image Name:" and 3 spaces before the actual name so if that's important to be parsed away, just use a for /f loop:

```
for /f "tokens=3 usebackq" %i in (`tasklist /fo list ^| find ^"Image Name^"`) do @echo %i
```

or of course inside a batch file double the percent signs to `%%i`.

If you're looking for all the information about the process, then I agree with @Harry Johnston on using format csv.  Depends on what you're going to do with it next, really.